# How can I let people download a file

Tags: html

I have a download link, which mysite.com/files/game.jar and that will download. But now I want people to download a folder with a text file and the jar file and a video. How can I do this?

PS: I have upload all the files to my site, but when I do mysite.com/files/game it just shows me all the files inside the 'game' folder.

Thanks!

Comment: Put the files in a .zip file and link to that. Or have you ever downloaded an entire (unzipped) foder from the Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest zipping / tarballing it up the folder and linking to that?
Would that not work?

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience I have not seen a way to download a whole directory. You would have to dynamically zip the folder and make the resulting zip downloadable.

You can download single file like:

```
<a href="/images/test.jpg" download="logo">
```

Hope, this gives you right path.